# Multiple ckeditor instances with same textarea name

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

i am working on adding multiple ckeditor on clicking add more button...i am loading a form on add more click using jquery...form having the five fields, one of which is description where i want to replace textarea with text editor.
only first ckeditor is working...ckeditor that appear in add more, are not working.
here is the html code

```
<div class="hid" id="multi_job_example">
            <div class="a-header">
            <div class="fright"><a href="#" class="delete_job">Remove job</a></div>
            <div class="slide"><ins class="i-o"></ins></div>
            <div class="text"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="a-block my-form" id="input1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email Address:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="text" name="ind_email[]" value="" id="email1" class="form-control"/></div>
            </div>      
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Job Description: </label>
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <textarea class="ckeditor" name="fe_description[]"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul id="more_job_list" class="a-list">
    </ul>


    <div class="b">
        <a href="#" id="add_job_link" class="btn-link"><ins class="with-icon i-list-add"></ins>Add more job</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$site_root}application/modules/controller/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$site_root}application/modules/mycontroller/js/add_multi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    new addMultiJob({
        counter: '',
        addLinkId: 'add_job_link',
        liListId: 'more_job_list',
        liIdPrefix: 'job_li_',
        exampleId: 'multi_job_example',
        deleteSelector: 'a.delete_job'
    });
});

</script>
```

below is the jquery code to add more fields in add_multi_job.js file

```
function addMultiJob(optionArr){
this.properties = {
    counter: 0,
    addLinkId: 'add_job_link',
    liListId: 'more_job_list',
    liIdPrefix: 'job_li_',
    exampleId: 'multi_job_example',
    deleteSelector: 'a.delete_job',
    headerSelector: 'input.ext_org',
    changed: false
}
var _self = this;

this.Init = function(options){
    _self.properties = $.extend(_self.properties, options);
    _self.properties.counter = parseInt(_self.properties.counter);

    $('#'+_self.properties.addLinkId).bind('click', function(){
        var content = $('#'+_self.properties.exampleId).html();
        _self.properties.counter++;
        content = content.replace(/__NUM__/g, _self.properties.counter);
        $('#'+_self.properties.liListId)
            .append('<li id="'+_self.properties.liIdPrefix+_self.properties.counter+'">'+content+'</li>');

        return false;
    });
    $('#'+_self.properties.liListId+' '+_self.properties.deleteSelector).live('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
        return false;
    });

    $('#'+_self.properties.liListId+' '+_self.properties.headerSelector).live('keyup', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.a-header .text').html($('<div/>').text($(this).val()).html());
    });

    $('#'+_self.properties.liListId+' .a-header .slide').live('click', function(){
        if($(this).find('ins').hasClass('i-o')){
            $(this).find('ins').removeClass('i-o').addClass('i-c');
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.a-block').slideUp();
        }else{
            $(this).find('ins').removeClass('i-c').addClass('i-o');
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.a-block').slideDown();
        }
    });

}
_self.Init(optionArr);
}
```

i'm using ckeditor 4.4.6
just including the js file from ckeditor plugin in my view file

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKEditor on appended textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135198/ckeditor-on-appended-textarea)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after adding the textarea by add more option you must have to fire (reinitialize) the ck editor.because the previous one does not apply on the dynamic content loading.

Comment: you mean i have to destroy previous editor than load the new one...?

Comment: no you have to just fire it again.with some new element (like class/id etc) or even you can fire it with the textarea tag again.it will just tell the ck editor to be loaded once more on some dynamic content.